# Show product star ratings and count below the price in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In woocommerce archive pages, I would like to move the ratings under the price.

Is that possible? How can I make it?

Here is What I would like:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

My [website link](http://drganja.com.s174560.gridserver.com/)

Comment: **This question is not too broad** even if the OP has not given any code. The working answer is **5 lines of code**. So please consider reopening this thread as **this question/answer is useful** to the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will move ratings below the price in Woocommerce archives pages:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','change_loop_ratings_location', 2 );
function change_loop_ratings_location(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 15 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition to get the rating count:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'loop_product_get_rating_html', 20, 3 );
function loop_product_get_rating_html( $html, $rating, $count ){
    if ( 0 < $rating && ! is_product() ) {
        global $product;
        $rating_cnt = array_sum($product->get_rating_counts());
        $count_html = ' <div class="count-rating">' . $rating_cnt .'</div>';

        $html       = '<div class="container-rating"><div class="star-rating">';
        $html      .= wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count );
        $html      .= '</div>' . $count_html . '</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

> Some additional CSS styling will be needed (and may be html structure changes)

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: your code works fine id you see there is counting number too I need it to display with same line into review thank you so much please little help too

Comment: Thank you  for help its works for me

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj - The above answer works, but how did you get the rating count to display with the same line as the review stars?

Comment: If there is no rating available, but still I want to display stars with 0 value. Is it possible?

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora … It is possible replacing the code line: `if ( 0 < $rating && ! is_product() ) {` by this one: `if ( 0 <= $rating && ! is_product() ) {` *(so just changing `<` by `<=`)* … so it will display empty stars with zero count if there is no ratings…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks a lot, it works perfectly.
I want to display the 0 valued star ratings to the product single page also, can you please help me.

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora where in the single product page?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec below the title of the product page

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora You should better ask a new question… and once done, warn me here.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you please [have a look to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487462/how-to-display-blank0-product-star-ratings-in-the-woocommerce-product-pages)